# what do I do with the x-1?(extraneous solutions)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the equation

$$\sqrt{3x+7}=x-1$$

I know I am supposed to put everything to the power of 2 but my question is why does the $x-1$ turn into $(x-1)^2$ instead of $x^2+1$?

Comment: Whatever you do to one side of an equation you must do to the other side, so if you take the left hand side to the power of two, you must also take the right hand side to the power of two.

Comment: Are you asking why $(x - 1)^2 \neq x^2 + 1$?

Comment: Seriously, are you asking why $(x-1)^2 \neq x^2+1$?

Comment: No I'm asking why the power goes over the whole term instead of raising the x and the -1 individually to the power of 2 .

Comment: @Jerryskidinosaur, You're not squaring both terms, your actually taking the entire expression, (x-1), and squaring that. if x= 5, (x-1)^2 would be 16, not 26, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't just raise individual terms to the power of two, you apply it to *the entirety* of each side of the equation.

$\sqrt{3x+7} = x-1 \\
\left(\sqrt{3x+7}\right)^2=\left(x-1\right)^2=\left(x-1\right)\left(x-1\right)=x^2-2x+1 \\
3x+7=x^2-2x+1 \\
\left(3x+7\right)-\left(3x+7\right)=\left(x^2-2x+1\right)-\left(3x+7\right) \\
0 = x^2-5x-6$

and so forth.

Alternatively, look at it like this:

$\sqrt{3x+7} = x-1 \\
\sqrt{3x+7} \times \sqrt{3x+7} = (x-1) \times \sqrt{3x+7} = (x-1) \times (x-1) = (x-1)^2$

Where first I just multiply both sides by $\sqrt{3x+7}$, then I use the starting equality to substitute $(x-1)$ for $\sqrt{3x+7}$.